Why this R random forest is unsupervised forest
data1 <- read.csv("R:/temp-15575615/Archaeal_tfpssm.csv", header = FALSE)
block=NA
data1 <- data1[, -5603]
data1$y0y <- sample(1:dim(data1)[1], dim(data1)[1], replace = FALSE)
block <- list()
data2<-data1
k<-6
for (i in 1:k) {
  block[[i]] <- subset(data2, data2 $y0y <= (dim(data1)[1]/k*i))
  data2 <- subset(data2, data2 $y0y > (dim(data1)[1] /k*i))
}
j<-1
test<-block[[(j-1)%%k+1]]
veri<-block[[j%%k+1]]
train<-block[[(j+1)%%k+1]]
for (i in 2:(k-2)){
  temp1<-block[[(j+i)%%k+1]]
  train<-rbind(train,temp1)
}
model <- randomForest(formula = V2 ~ V3:V5602, x = train, ntree = 1, mtry = 50, maxnodes = 70, keep.forest = TRUE)
predictions <- predict(model, train, type = "prob")

than error occur at predict.randomForest(model, train, type = "prob")：
Can't predict unsupervised forest.
I searched google use keyword "Can't predict unsupervised forest" can't find something useful so I ask this question,and I don't know where is other resources,I hope can get the bug fix idea . file

Welcome to SO, Rosalina Rosalina! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using dput(head(x)), data.frame(..), read.table(..), or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

On a sidenote: putting a blank between a list and the $ operator does work, but it's very unconventional. Better make a habit of writing data2$y0y instead of data2 $y0y ;-)
